# Is preventing XSS/HTML Injection really this simple?

Tags: web-application, xss, injection, html

A colleague suggested to me just to prevent letter characters from occurring immediately after an opening angle bracket as a way to protect against XSS and HTML injection.

Obviously, this doesn't prevent issues such as:

```
<img src="%injectable%" />
```

But I can't think of a way around his suggestion.

Is it really that simple?

Comment: Could you be more specific about either the context & the type of XSS you're thinking of? Otherwise I'd say it's a pretty moot protection overall.

Comment: What language or platform are you using?  Usually the templating system you are using has an XSS filter.

Comment: What is the exact suggestion?  Just ban /<[a-z]/i ? In which context would it be run? As you show, if the attacker is able to inject content inside a tag (or a `<script>`, `<style>`… ) you are still vulnerable, so I don't understand you statement that you "can't think of a way around his suggestion" while showing a counter-example at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

I think your example describes exactly why it isn't that simple.  There are many forms of XSS, and quite a few of them don't rely on attackers injecting entire tags at all.

What Rook was getting at in his comment is that you should generally rely on a good existing XSS filter to deal with the threat rather than trying to piece one together your own, as your colleague seems to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

White-listing the characters is always the best practice instead of black-listing special characters.
I had seen the same thing with one of the apps I was assessing. So, I found an input parameter which showed in response at three different places. One of which was inside " " in a-tags. No wonder, XSS was easy there.
And yes, already mentioned, many of the payloads don't have to use tags at all.